# Wordpress Get Posts AJAX infinate scroll

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming, infinite-scroll

I'm working on a website http://www.matchlessphotography.com which has got a great display of photos - it tiles for ages...

[image]

Essentially the client would like this to continue on infinately.

I have no idea how to do this and have had a look at some tutorials without any bearing...

---

This is how I am currently getting the posts:

```
<?php

        global $post;

        $args = array('numberposts'     => 104, 'meta_key=visible&meta_value=yes');
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

                <a class="photohovera" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>            

                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<? echo $url ?>&h=138&w=197" width="197" height="138" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />

                    <span class="spanno">

                        <strong class="title_blog_mini_post">

                        <?php the_title(); ?>

                        </strong>

                    </span>

                </a>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I guess I just need to do this again but with an increased offset each time...?

Answer (score 0):

Paul Irishs [jQuery Plugin Infinite Scroll](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/) is the way to go here.

The plugin looks for a pagination container e.g. `div.navigation` and an item container for the items you are going to retrieve like `.photohovera` in your case.

WordPress provides a function for displaying pagination links. It's called [paginate_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) and its default output should match the requirements of the plugin.

However you will need to change they way you are getting your posts right now from get_posts() to a [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) Object:

```
<?php
$args = array('numberposts'     => 104, 'meta_key=visible&meta_value=yes');
$myposts = new WP_Query( $args );
$results = $myposts->get_results();
foreach( $results as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
```